Solving the Diophantine equation $ab(a+b)=T$, where $a$ and $T$ are triangular numbers
How to solve the Diophantine equation, $ab(a+b)=T$, for positive integers, where $a$ is any given Triangular number & $T$ are also certain Triangular numbers?
As of, $(a,b,T)=(3,7,210), (3,82,20910), ...$

You can first look to $ab(a+b)=n$ in general, see here.

other examples:  $(1,2,6), (1,14,20), (3,5,120), (3,62,155)$

@J.W.Tanner Thanks for giving other examples. But the problem asks for any given Triangular number $a$ such that with the positive integer $b$, $T$ is a Triangular number.

I meant $(1,14,210)$; also $(3,62,12090)$; also $(6,17,23460)$ and $(10,39,19110)$; I haven't solved the problem, just shown there are many examples

@J.W.Tanner of course there should be many examples & there are. But the miracle lies in finding out "all" those examples.

Should have been $2346$ where I typed $23460$

@J.W.Tanner a subtle & humble query. You have solved the case for $a=1$. How you are bringing out other examples of other cases for $a$?

This question is similar to: Determine if integer can be factored as $ab(a+b)$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Servaes:  this question is asking for $ab(a+b)$ to be a triangular number

Another method:
Substitute $a=n(n+1)/2$ and $T=m(m+1)/2$ into $ab(a+b)=T,$ we get
$$(2n+2n^2)b^2+(n^4+n^2+2n^3)b-2m^2-2m=0\tag{1}$$
Let consider the equation $(1)$ as the quadratic equation for $(b,m).$
Since the equation $(1)$ has an integer solution $(b,m)=(0,0)$, we apply the Gauss's theorem to the equation $(1).$ We know that
the equation $(1)$ has infinitely many integer solutions for any integer $n>0.$
Hence,  $ab(a+b)=T$ has infinitely many integer solutions where $a$ is any given Triangular number.
Gauss's theorem:(Mordell's book, Diophantine Equations, $p.57$)
Given one integer solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of the equation
$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy +cy^2 + dx +ey +f=0,$ where the coefficients are integers, there exists an infinity of integer solutions
if $D=b^2-4ac>0,$is not a perfect square, and if the discriminant=$4acf+bde-ac^2-cd^2-fb^2 \neq 0.$

Numerical example for $a=3$(partial solution).
                          [a,b,T]

                        [3, 7, 210]
                      [3, 82, 20910]
                     [3, 825, 2049300]
                   [3, 8180, 200810820]
                  [3, 80987, 19677411390]
                [3, 801702, 1928185505730]
               [3, 7936045, 188942502150480]
             [3, 78558760, 18514437025241640]
            [3, 777651567, 1814225885971530570]
          [3, 7697956922, 177775622388184754550]


This is a partial solution, the case where $a=1$:
$b(1+b)=\dfrac {n(n+1)}2\iff 2b(b+1)=n(n+1)\iff 2\left(\left(b+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14\right)=\left(n+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$
$\iff2(\left(2b+1)^2-1\right)=(2n+1)^2-1\iff(2n+1)^2-2(2b+1)^2=-1$.
$N^2-2B^2=-1$ is the negative Pell equation; the solutions for $B$ are given in OEIS.

Quite intriguing & a Marvelous solution for case $a=1$. Can we apply this same procedure for any given Triangular number $a$?

Maybe - I haven't tried - perhaps you should try - I suspect you might come up with a generalized Pell equation

Thanks a lot for editing the Tags of the problem. Anyway, I was just curious to know about, that, can there be an empirical formula, from which we can deduce $b$ for a given $a$ such that $T$ is again a Triangular number?

Let $T=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$. Then $2a(4b^2+4ba)=4n(n+1)$ so, defining $s=2n+1$, $t=2b+a$, you have $s^2-(2a)t^2=-(2a^3-1)$ which is indeed a (generalised) Pell equation, as J. W. Tanner suggested in his answer, and one solution of the equation is $s=1$, $t=a$; to find further solutions, we need to solve the Pell equation $s^2-(2a)t^2=1$. Note that $a$ is also a triangle number: say $a=\frac{1}{2}p(p+1)$; then a solution is given by $s= 2p+1$, $t=2$. This means, by the standard method for solving Pell equations, that we have an infinite set of solutions generated by $s_0=1$, $t_0$ =$a$ and $$s_{i+1}=(2p+1)s_i+4at_i \quad \mbox{and} \quad  t_{i+1}=2s_i+(2p+1)t_i\, .$$ This does not give all the solutions - another sequence is generated by starting from the solution $s=-1$, $t=a$, for instance.

$$ab(a+b)=T$$
Substitute $a=n(n+1)/2$ and $T=m(m+1)/2$ into $ab(a+b)=T,$ we get
$$n^4b+2n^3b+2n^2b^2+n^2b+2nb^2-2m^2-2m=0$$
For the quadratic in $m$  to have integral solutions, the discriminant must be a perfect square.
Hence, this problem is reduced to the problem of finding the integral solutions for the quartic equation.
$$v^2 = 2bn^4+4bn^3+(2b+4b^2)n^2+4b^2n+1$$
Search results for $b<100$ with $n<10000.$
The rational points are obtained using the hyperellratpoints function in PARI/GP as follows.
>hyperellratpoints($2bX^4+4bX^3+(2b+4b^2)X^2+4b^2X+1,10000$);
There are more solutions, $(a,b,T)=(21, 125, 383250),(28, 195, 1217580),(55, 549, 18237780),(91, 1182, 136926426).$
Thus, there always exists an integral solution $(a,b,T)$ for $a<100.$
             (a,b,T)

            [1, 2, 6]
            [1, 14, 210]
            [1, 84, 7140]
            [3, 5, 120]
            [3, 7, 210]
            [3, 62, 12090]
            [3, 82, 20910]
            [6, 17, 2346]
            [6, 19, 2850]
            [10, 39, 19110]
            [10, 41, 20910]
            [15, 9, 3240]
            [15, 13, 5460]
            [15, 74, 98790]
            [15, 76, 103740]
            [36, 14, 25200]
            [36, 77, 313236]
            [45, 13, 33930]
            [66, 14, 73920]
            [66, 12, 61776]
            [66, 62, 523776]
            [78, 77, 930930]
            [105, 66, 1185030]
            [105, 77, 1471470]
            [105, 32, 460320]
            [231, 82, 5928846]
            [300, 71, 7902300]
            [406, 45, 8239770]
            [595, 29, 10767120]
            [666, 65, 31644990]
            [1326, 74, 137373600]
            [1540, 92, 231221760]

